# How to Publish an Umbraco Intranet?

Tags: visual-studio, iis, umbraco, umbraco7

I have just completed an Umbraco intranet using WebMatrix. Now I want to publish it to our server so that everybody can see and use it. WebMatrix can only do Web Deploy or FTP, so I opened the project in Visual Studio 2013 to publish it there. I was able to publish it to my desktop, where I have attempted to get it running here before uploading to the server. So in IIS I 'Add a Website' and set up the project, using port 101. I tried it both on my desktop and then moved it to wwwroot and in both cases IE says 'This page can't be displayed'. I am using the CE database with Umbraco 7.2.4.

Help please. I've been at this for days now.... I've tried the umbraco forum and google and got nowhere. :(

Tony

Comment: Why port 101 and not 80? What version of IIS is installed on the server? Can you try browsing the site locally on the server, to see if that gives you a more detailed error description? Have all the necessary files been correctly published? I'm thinking the /bin/ dll's, the /umbraco/ and /umbraco_client/ folders and so on.

You could also try just copying all the files over, instead of creating a local deploy first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I copied (unpublished) the complete project onto the server in the meantime and it runs only in WebMatrix. I can't get it to run in IIS, it's IIS 8 we're using. I tried to generate a PUBLISH SETTINGS file for Umbraco to try to publish it on the server, but WebMatrix couldn't find the server! I tried port 80, 82, 84,85, 101, I was just trying a few in case it was a problem.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. But yeah, sounds more like an IIS issue than Umbraco.

Comment: Thanks anyway Jannik!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have remote desktop access to your web server, you don't actually need to rely on web publishing. You can just build the website in release mode, and then copy all the folders from the web project onto the webserver.

On the web server you can manually set up an IIS website and set up host names etc. You shouldn't need to deploy it using visual studio, this way is much safer

Comment: Since I posted I have done that Carl. I uploaded the site, set up IIS, the host name, but it isn't running. I think the problem is an asp.net issue. I have uninstalled iis, with the idea of reinstalling iis with all the correct roles and features and now the server has crashed! It did an update and lost the GUI!

Comment: Yes - that does sound like IIS not behaving correctly. If you can host a basic asp.net app (just a standard out of the box sample from visual studio correctly, then you should also be able to host umbraco correctly - there's no real additional requirement

Comment: I got it! I had to uninstall iis and reinstall it with asp.net and application server. The server lost the gui during the uninstallation, so that was another delay. Dism /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:Server-Gui-Mgmt /featurename:Server-Gui-Shell /featurename:ServerCore-FullServer brought it back. Sorted!

Comment: Nice one. If you get the time, making a few notes and editing your original comment might help others in the same boat as you, but I'm glad it's all sorted

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, you should set up a new website, using port 80 on your HTTP binding.

From the sounds of the error, IIS is not looking at the right physical path.

You should use the Microsoft guide on [How to set up your first IIS Web Site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323972) as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found a guide for iis8 and followed, though it is my first so I'm bound to have messed up, I just don't know what I did wrong. I've since changed the port to 80, but same result. I tried changing the ip address from 'all available' to that of the server, that did nothing either. The page still can't be displayed.